# The redundancy of forward_iterator concept?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, c++-concepts

In [[iterator.concept.forward]](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.forward#1), `std::forward_iterator` is defined as:

```
template<class I>
  concept forward_­iterator =
    input_­iterator<I> &&
    derived_­from<ITER_CONCEPT(I), forward_iterator_tag> &&
    incrementable<I> &&
    sentinel_­for<I, I>;
```

and [`std::sentinel_for<I, I>`](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.sentinel#concept:sentinel_for) is defined as:

```
template<class S, class I>
  concept sentinel_­for =
    semiregular<S> &&
    input_­or_­output_­iterator<I> &&
    weakly-equality-comparable-with<S, I>;
```

which seems to be redundant in `std::forward_iterator`'s requirement, since `input_iterator` already models `input_or_output_iterator`, and [`incrementable`](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.inc#concept:incrementable) is defined as:

```
template<class I>
  concept incrementable =
    regular<I> &&
    weakly_­incrementable<I> &&
    requires(I i) {
      { i++ } -> same_­as<I>;
    };
```

which models [`regular`](http://eel.is/c++draft/concepts.object#concept:regular) which models `semiregular` and [`equality_­comparable`](http://eel.is/c++draft/concept.equalitycomparable#concept:equality_comparable) which models `weakly-equality-comparable-with<I, I>`.

Why does the standard need to add a constraint that seems redundant here, and what are the considerations behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concepts have explicit syntactical requirements (ie: these expressions have to compile), but they also have implicit semantic concepts. `equality_comparable<T>` has a semantic requirement that if `t == u`, then `t` and `u` have the same value, however that is defined for `T`.

But `sentinel_for` requires a more specific meaning for `t == u`. Equality between a sentinel and an iterator means that the iterator is at the end of the range (and therefore, you aren't allowed to dereference it).

So these concepts are not redundant; they are needed to express the semantic meaning of `forward_iterator<T>`. In this case, that testing one iterator against another is a valid way to check for the end of the sequence. And therefore, the meaning of "value" for a forward iterator is "position in the range".

Answer (score 4):

`forward_­iterator` needs the semantic requirements of `sentinel_for`. Those are not implied by either `regular` or `equality_comparable`.